# How do I add a C# solution file in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

In Rider, if I open a folder that has a single .csproj file in it, how do I add a solution? Is there a way to do it inside Rider, like there is in Visual Studio, without resorting to the command line and closing/re-opening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you can do this with Rider 2019.1 now.

Go to File -> New -> gives the option to add a new solution.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no way in Rider to toggle between folder mode and solution mode like you can do in Visual Studio.

The rest depends on what your intention is.

If you opened a folder containing a *.csproj* with *File | Open File or Folder* and you realized you were unable to build, debug or run your .NET application in this mode, you should just re-open it with *File | Open Solution or Project*, pointing Rider to the *.csproj* file.

If the above is not an issue but you want to take your existing *.csproj* project and wrap it into a *.sln* file, then select *File | New Solution | Empty Solution*, and when the new solution loads, add your existing project to it by right-clicking the solution node in *Solution Explorer* and selecting *Add Existing Project*.

Comment: I think you can switch between Folder (called FileSystem in Rider 2018.2) and Solution at the top of the solution explorer. I guess I will have to do as you suggest and manually add a solution file and then add the project to it. Thanks for the reply:)